# making a new tk OptionMenu class to add desired formatting

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm working on a project for myself, I'm not a great programmer or anything, but I was wanting to add a bit of formatting to the OptionMenu class.  In typical tk you call optionmenu with a list and it then iterates through that list to make the various .add_commands.   i.e.

```
Button >>
  Sword
  Dagger
  Axe
  Great Sword
  Great Axe
```

What I was wanting to do though was add in a visual separator (Not tk's default horizontal rule) that would distinct those items by a 'weapon class' ie.

```
 Button >>
  1-Hand --
    Sword
    Dagger
    Axe
  2-Hand --
    Great Sword
    Great Axe
```

Where the separator, obviously, wasn't a selectable option.  So I figured I could write a new class 'myOptionMenu2'.  I can generate a widget that appears identical to tk's 'OptionMenu' but I'm not really sure how it's best to implement the drawing of the actual menu itself.

If it inherits tk's (MenuButton) class (like optionmenu does), I assume(?) that I could write a new 'add_separator()' function that would step-on tk's default add-separator function, and i could use that to just insert Label widgets

Or i could just inherit a Frame and cut out all the need to mess with tk's menu/menubutton coding. But I am unsure exactly how tk() implements the 'top-level' frames for menu (with no borders, drop shadow, etc.)  I looked in the actual tk.py but I'm still not certain i understand how it accomplishes it.

my overall desire is to invoke it something like this:

```
baseList = [
           [1-hand,[sword,dagger,axe, ...]],
           [2-hand,[Great Sword, Great Axe, ...]]
           [ ..., [...]] #as needed
           ]


myOptionMenu2(master, a_parent_IntVar(), baseList)
```

and then have the class draw the 'button', parse the list and handle clicks.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have very little leeway in what you can do on the menus. Your only options are the ones provided by the tk menu widget. You can't, for example, add a label to the menu. However, you can add a command that does nothing, which can serve as a label.

There's also the problem that an optionmenu isn't really a class under the covers. In tk (which Tkinter is built upon), the option menu is just a helper function that contructs a menubutton and a menu. So, there's simply no way to override the `add_separator` method.

That being said, it's pretty easy to write your own class that creates the menubutton and associated menu. You can then do whatever the standard widgets allows you to do, such as using non-functioning commands as labels.

Here's a simple example:

```
class myOptionMenu2(tk.Menubutton):
    def __init__(self, parent, var, data):
        tk.Menubutton.__init__(self, parent, borderwidth=1, relief="raised",
                               textvariable=var, indicatoron=True)
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.configure(menu=self.menu)

        default = None
        for (category, weapons) in data:
            self.menu.add_command(label=category, command=None)
            if default is None:
                default = weapons[0]
                var.set(default)

            for weapon in weapons:
                self.menu.add_radiobutton(indicatoron=True, value=weapon,
                    label=weapon, variable=var)
```

You could use it like this:

```
baseList = [
    ["1-Hand", ["sword", "dagger", "axe"]],
    ["2-Hand", ["Great Sword", "Great Axe"]]
]

weaponVar = tk.StringVar()
om = myOptionMenu2(self, weaponVar, baseList)
```

You also have the option of making cascade menus. So, the dropdown would have entries for "1-Hand" and "2-Hand", and each of those would have a menu for the various options. You could start with the above code, and instead of making commands you can create cascade items.

Finally, you could do what you suggest in the last part of your question and create your own menu-like object out of a toplevel frame (with the `overrideredirect` flag set to True). You then have complete control over what the dropdown looks like. You could, for example, embed a canvas and draw whatever you want. This solution would require a fair amount of code, though.

Comment: Thanks for the info on overrideredirect. As far as drawing on the menus, I didn't ask if i could draw on the menus, I asked what is the best way to circumvent the base options provided by tk. And regarding all the 'code writing',  I included in my post, that that was a possibility i was entertaining. In fact my first one.

These types of answers are why this is site is the forum of last resorts for me.  The people here are like that pompous, father-in-law stereotype, that no one ever wants to ask for money because they don't want to hear a load of bullshit.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy: I'm sorry if I offended you. In rereading your question I see I slightly misunderstood your question. I'll rephrase my answer. In short, yes, you can add your own labels to the menu. Not label _widgets_, but commands that do nothing so they are effectively labels.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy: I've rewritten my answer. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for your time, sorry if I came off brash.  Your attention was appreciated.